# Php get dates inside a string

Tags: php, regex, date, preg-match

I have a string like this:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean 2017-03-31 ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. 2016-03-04 sociis natoque penatibus...

I would like to get all the dates inside the text... the format dates are always `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: try regular expressions, get the right pattern to match the dates and then use that pattern within the preg_match function , see http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use preg_match and regex expression:

```
$string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean 2017-03-31 ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. 2016-03-04 sociis natoque penatibus...";
$pattern = '/([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

To test regex, I suggest you to use https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1):

Alright so what you have to do is figure out what you are trying to find, in your case `yyyy-mm-dd`.

So this would be it:

```
[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match("/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}/", $input_line, $output_array);
```